# KDE Plasma how to hide second task manager

Tags: debian, task-manager

I just installed debian with KDE plasma. The weird thing is that my screen shows a task manager at the bottom as well at the top. Of course I don't need two task managers..  but I cannot find any way to remove it. How do I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Task Manager` is just like any other `widget` present on the `panel`. Follow these steps to remove second Task Manager :

- **Unlock Widgets** If panel is locked. Right-Click on the panel to get this option. Click on `Unlock Widgets`.

[image: Unlock Widgets]

- Now you will see `Burger Menu Icon` at rightmost of the panel. Click that to **`Customize Panel`**.

[image: Burger Menu]

- When you hover any widget, you'll see a **`Remove Widget`** button (cross in red circle) . So, Hover over to Task Manager Section on panel and just Press that button.

[image: System Tray]

Feel free to add-in more details.

Answer (score 2):

1. Click on the options box which is right next to your clock on the task manager. That way, you'll enter **Edit** mode. (Here is an example of how it should look like, despite having a different visual theme: 

   [image: Edit button for KDE task manager] (the lines on the right of the digital clock represent the button you need to click on)
2. Then, simply hover over the extra task manager, and a pop-up showing it's name ("Task manager") and a close button appear.
3. Click on the close button, that should remove the task manager from your screen.